# trouble installing ruby 2.0.0 on Trusty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

People are having trouble installing ruby 2, I've tried all solutions found on this forum but none help, and, I have found no one with **quite** the same problem I have:

Here my progress so far (in a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2*
```

which worked fine, then:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p561
```

(numbers after the "p" might be wrong, I'm writing from memory here, since my Guake-terminal only scrolls back 1024 lines, and I've since had way more errors than that)

All good but now it gets weird!

```
cd path/to/project/requiring/ruby2.0.0
rails s
```

giving me the error:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

say what? Trying to prove my computer wrong, I tried:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

What's going on?

tried reinstalling everything, working my way around broken packages and other fun stuff, only to get the same result

Any help?

Comment: I recommend installing Ruby with RVM (or rbenv if you prefer it). Here's a tutorial to [Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html).

Comment: check http://www.gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

Comment: Thanks Daniel! RVM seems to be the way to go, now I can switch between 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 at will! Would you go through the trouble of making that suggest a reply, so that I can mark this solved?

Answer (score 0):

`Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0`

This sounds like the bundler error. If you check at the top of the Gemfile you should see something like.

`ruby '2.0.0'`

This line of the Gemfile is a way for the programmer to indicate what Ruby version they were expecting when running the application. In your case you had 1.9.3 but bundler required 2.0.0.

From [bundler.io](http://bundler.io)

[Bundler will make checks against the current running Ruby VM to make sure it matches what is specified in the Gemfile. If things don't match, Bundler will raise an Exception explaining what doesn't match.](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile_ruby.html)

[Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile_ruby.html)

[RVM](https://rvm.io/) is simply a tool that allows you to have multiple versions of Ruby on one machine. It allowed you to install 2.0.0, which stopped the exception, but it wasn't the root of the problem. The root was the disparity in Ruby versions.

Rich